# Install Swift in fedora 18

Tags: linux, swift, installation, fedora

I'm trying to install Swift in fedora 18. I ran:

```
yum install swift
```

and ran successful but I have not found a way to execute any swift file.

I'll really appreciate your help if any of you knows how to install and configure Swift in fedora 18.

Comment: That is the rpm for a chat/instant messaging program and has nothing to do with the swift language.

Comment: Install some up to date Fedora. Version 18 is years after EOL.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple Github repositories with Fedora build scripts that will help: [FedoraSwift/fedora-swift](https://github.com/FedoraSwift/fedora-swift) and [corinnekrych/swift-rpm](https://github.com/corinnekrych/swift-rpm).

Comment: I ran this command "sudo dnf install libbsd python gcc-c++ clang" but I'm getting this error:"sudo: dnf: command not found" using this instructions https://github.com/corinnekrych/swift-rpm

Comment: Have you upgraded to the required version of Fedora? dnf is the replacement for yum.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to execute swift binaries in not Ubuntu linux is to use [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/swift/)